# how to get downloading status of video when go back to previous controller and again came back?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hai here Am downloading a video and storing it to documents folder in iphone... but when i click on download button video will start downloading and progress will show nicely... but when i go back to previous view controller and came back to the downloading controller during downloading the progress view status will not show the current status... can anybody help me to solve this? thanks in advance...

Here is my code...

```
- (void)downLoad:(UIButton *)sender {
_downloadBtn.hidden = YES;
_videoData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
_resourceName = [_resourceNameArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
_resourceType = [_contentTypesArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag];

NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_videoUrlArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag]];
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]] delegate:self ];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
NSLog(@"Downloading Started");
_length = [response expectedContentLength];
NSLog(@"Size:%0.2f",_length);
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    [_videoData appendData:data];
    float progress = (float)[_videoData length]/(float)_length;
    NSLog(@"Progress:%0.2f",progress);
    //_timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2F%%",progress*100];
    [_progressView setProgress:progress animated:YES];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"didFailWithError");
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
[self saveLocally:_videoData res:_resourceName type:_resourceType];
NSLog(@"File Saved !");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Download screen -> previous screen -> Download screen. Let's try:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data 
{
[_videoData appendData:data];
float progress = (float)[_videoData length]/(float)_length;
NSLog(@"Progress:%0.2f",progress);
NSNumer *n = [NSNumber numberWithFloatValue:progress];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS object:n];

//_timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2F%%",progress*100];
[_progressView setProgress:progress animated:YES];
}
```

When you go back to download screen, you should update progress by receive notification

```
#define  NOTIFICATION_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS @"NOTIFICATION_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS"
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(processProgressBar:) name:NOTIFICATION_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS object:nil];
}

- (void) processProgressBar:(NSNumber *) progress
{
[_progressView setProgress: progress.floatValue];
}
```

Comment: it shows undeclared variable "NOTIFICATION_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS"

Comment: app is crashing at [_progressView setProgress: progress.floatValue];